# how to save Vlp-16 results

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone I am new in Ros and Lidar.

My project is finding humans in VLP-16 lidar output.

To do that, I have a camera and vlp-16. I need to save images from camera and data from VLP-16. Then I will label corresponding pixels and train them with a ML algorithm.

I am saving images from camera with system time name (30 fps), and I want to save VLP-16 output with x,y,z and intensity.
But I could not find how to save VLP-16 output data into a file.

I would be thankful if you could help me about it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258547/how-to-save-vlp-16-results/) by [eneski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29925/eneski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dongyun2378](https://answers.ros.org/users/30280/dongyun2378/) on 2017-05-06**:
Hi everyone
My project is similar to eneski's, it is necessary to synchronize the data of VLP-16 and image. However,I don't know how to save Synchronous data.I have successfully installed velodyne /ROS-drivers and it can work normally.
@eneski :Have you saved the data successfully?   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usual method for saving ROS messages for later processing is via the [rosbag record](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#record) command.

For velodyne data, it's better to record the [/velodyne_packets topic](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_driver?distro=indigo#Published_Topics) published by the driver. Those messages contain all the data that are subsequently published as a point cloud, but in much more compact form.

For your camera images, you may want to consider saving their compressed format:

- http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport#Published_topics

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eneski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29925/eneski/) on 2017-04-12**:
Thaks for your answer,

I have one more question:

Can I get only distance(z) for each frame? Do you know how to do that?

**Comment by [eneski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29925/eneski/) on 2017-04-12**:
I just want to write all z distance to a file and then I will process them. Because x and y are obviously known, I don't really need them.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-04-12**:
I don't quite understand your subsequent question. Please open a new question for that, and try to explain it more clearly.

**Comment by [eneski](https://answers.ros.org/users/29925/eneski/) on 2017-04-13**:
my question is special for you, I'm thinking that you made or ( at least know ) this ( [http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~piyushk/courses/spr12/slides/Week6b-print.pdf](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Epiyushk/courses/spr12/slides/Week6b-print.pdf) ) presentation. I just want to know how to run the subscriber.cc in the example. I would be very glad if you could help me.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-04-16**:
@piyushk made that for a class lecture and assignment. His students were expected to write and run the subscriber based on the hints provided.